# Is it possible to pass variables from add_user_page?

Tags: admin-menu, sub-menu

If have hooked into admin-menu like this:

```
function adminmenu_users_reserves(){    
    add_users_page('Reserver', 'Reserver', 'read', 'reserve_list', 'show_userlist');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adminmenu_users_reserves' );
```

and have a function

```
function show_userlist(show_reserves = true, $title) {
   code...
}
```

Can I pass variables `$show_reserves` FROM `add_users_page()` somehow? (In one case I need `$show_reserves` to be true, in other case I need it to be false)

Or would I have to solve my issue with two different functions like this? (for almost the same functionality)

```
function adminmenu_users_reserves(){    
    add_users_page('Reserves', 'Reserves', 'read', 'reserve_list', 'show_reservelist');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adminmenu_users_reserves' );

function adminmenu_users_registered(){    
    add_users_page('Registered', 'Registered', 'read', 'registered_list', 'show_registeredlist');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adminmenu_users_registered' );
```

**UPDATE**
Because I've got such a great answer from toscho (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho) I want to share my solution - if someone else has the same issue in the future:

```
class userList
{
    public $show_reserves = false;
    public $title = 'Reserver';

    //Show a list of all reserves/or registered users in the system ordered by register-date
    function render() {

        $reserves = $this->show_reserves;
        $title = $this->title;        

        echo $title;
        if ($reserves === true) {
            ....code...
        }
     }
}

function adminmenu_users_reserves(){    
    $userlist = new userList();
    add_users_page('Reserver', 'Reserver', 'read', 'reserve_list', array( $userlist, 'render' ));
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adminmenu_users_reserves' );

function adminmenu_users_registered(){    
    $userlist = new userList();
    $userlist->show_reserves = false;
    $userlist->title = 'Anmälda';
    add_users_page('Anmälda', 'Anmälda', 'read', 'registered_list', array( $userlist, 'render' ));
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adminmenu_users_registered' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most clean way to solve that problem is using a specialised object.

First create a class that can hold extra information:

```
class Menu_Page
{
    public $extra = '';

    public function render()
    {
        print $this->extra;
    }
}
```

Now create an object from that class …

```
$page        = new Menu_Page;
$page->extra = 'Hello World!';
```

… and register its method `render()` as callback:

```
add_users_page( 
    'Test', 
    'Test', 
    'manage_options', 
    'test', 
    array( $page, 'render' ) 
);
```

Comment: Somewhat "complicated" code just for this purpose, but thank you for the elegant solution! :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld You can build the class in such a way that you can reuse it in the same project or in multiple projects. After a while you will find the old way _too complicated_. :)

Comment: I agree that oop is the best way to do programming, but I just meant that such a simple task should have been easier to implement :-)